# Google Earth Engine, hide widgets in Map.ui

Tags: google-earth-engine

Can I hide all widgets in https://code.earthengine.google.com/ when loading a map?
(all standard widgets including +-(zoom), map/satellite, drawing tools...)

I would like to create an app and embed it into a website without the widgets, 
just displaying the loaded dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can hide all of the controls.

```js
Map.setControlVisibility({all: false});
```

Depending on your application, you might also want to prevent it from being panned or zoomed:

```js
Map.setLocked(true);
```

These examples are for the default map, but the same methods are also applicable to any `ui.Map` objects you create in your app if you are setting up a custom UI from scratch.